# Powershell command to return end date

Tags: powershell-4.0

I'm trying to get yesterday date to include the hour... for the start date, I'm using:

```
$startDate = (get-date).AddDays(-1).Date
```

This works as it returns the date with 12:00:00 AM at the end.

The end date is where I am stuck.. I need it end with 11:59:59 PM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the end of today you need something like this:

```
$endDate =  (get-date).Date.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1)
```

- Take now (`get-date`)
- Remove all time part using `.Date`.
- This is now the beginning of today.
- Add a Day (`.AddDays(1)`) to make it the start of tomorrow.
- Remove 1 second (`.AddSeconds(-1)`) to make it the end of today.

If you want the end of yesterday, remove the `.AddDays(1)` - it's unclear from your question.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, yes removing the .addDays(1) did the trick, didn't even think about using the addseconds... thanks for the help.